# Provide variables as input arguments to MATLAB system command for a C++ executable

Tags: c++, c, matlab, system

I have an algorithm implemented in MATLAB. I want to replace different built-in operations with my own C++ implementations. I do not want to use MEX for its extra overhead. Is there any way to provide variables as input arguments to my C++ executable function using the "system" command. For example, for a multiplier implemented in C++, the following works.

```
result = system('multiplier.exe 10 50')
```

The result is 500. But the following does not work:

```
a = 10;
b = 50;  
result = system('multiplier.exe a b');
```

The result is always 0 in this case.
I have tried to use setenv and getenv functions. But the result is still 0.
Any help??

Comment: Think on what a and b mean in the context of a string.

Comment: `system(['multiplier.exe ' num2str(a) ' ' num2str(b)])`?

Comment: @Evgeny Sorry I didn't see your comment before posting my answer. It was posted within some seconds after your comment

Comment: @SardarUsama, no worries. I upvoted.

Comment: Worth a quick test to make sure the overhead of `system` doesn't exceed the overhead of invoking a mex file. Been a while since I've played with MATLAB Either one may have gotten better or worse.

Comment: "I do not want to use MEX for its extra overhead" -- Wow, this sounds really misguided. `system` has a large overhead, it needs to start a new process, and load the executable, and you need to convert your numeric values to strings, and then convert the result back from a string... What is the overhead of a MEX-file? At the first call it needs to be loaded, but subsequent calls the overhead is approximately zero.

Answer (score 3):

As hinted by [user4581301](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4581301/user4581301) in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51883715/provide-variables-as-input-arguments-to-matlab-system-command-for-a-c-executab#comment90719105_51883715), your code is taking `a` and `b` as the strings `a` and `b` literally, and not translating them as `10` and `50` as expected by you. You need to put the values of `a` and `b` after converting them to strings instead. i.e.

```matlab
result = system(['multiplier.exe ', num2str(a), ' ', num2str(b)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Matlab is passing them as string.

Trying to write your values to a file and reading from those file inside the said program might be a work around. But if your inputs/outputs are long and you want them to have appropriate data type, than you might want to filter the input and output streams (stdin stdout) from matlab and cpp to get the appropriate behavior.